# Enhance 3D kinect render performance inside a WPF application with Helix 3d Toolikt

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, helix-3d-toolkit

i'm making a little app for create a 3d model from multiple kinects (in real-time!), and i'm using as BIG source of ispiration the Helix 3D Toolkit kinect example, it works great!

Sadly it has veeeeery poor performance and looks like the CPU gets all the work :( i know i must use something more powerfull than Helix 3D for this kind of stuff but i need to complete my project quickly and i don't have time to learn slimDX, sharpGL, openTK or whatelse (they all require to write a shader to do this kind of stuff, a little too time burning!)

So, this is what i got now:

[image: demo1]

it's cool but i got very poor performance. I can enhance a little lowering depth sensor resolution to 80x60, getting this:

[image: demo2]

a little toooo blurry, but with very good performance :D

this result is got creating a `GeometryModel3D`, editing its Geometry, Material and Transform value. Inside the Geometry now i have a `MeshGeometry3D`, with good results but poor performance (the cpu need to regenerate all the triangles at every frame!).
The `MeshGeometry3D` is composed by `Positions`, `TextureCoordinates` and `TriangleIndices` properties, like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.aspx) says. I like to mess all and i tried to remove the `TriangleIndices` values getting this:

[image: all messed up]

Useless but with better performance. But now i have some hope, looks like i have lots of lines (or very distorted triangles?) with some good placed vertices.

What i can do for having something accetable here? Even something like a cloud point it's perfectly fine, i just need to have nice performance!